# Reparent branch use TFS Api

Tags: tfs

I use tfs 2013 and is it possible to change parent of branch ,use tfs api and do it programmatically

Can we do reparent process over tfs api

Answer (score 0):

If it is a workitem that you are talking about, you sure can! 
I would look for the parent link and remove the old link and add a new parent workitem link.

Remove Parent Link:

```
WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linkTypEnd = workitemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Parent"];
foreach (WorkItemLink link in wi.WorkItemLinks)
{
 if (link.LinkTypeEnd.Name == linkTypEnd.Name && link.TargetId == wiID)
    {
      wi.Links.Remove(link);
      wi.Save();
     }
 }
```

Then Add a New Parent Link:
which should be pretty straightforward. I had issues looking for the Parent LinkTypeEnd. I tried using the System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy workitem link type.

```
WorkItemLinkType linkType = workitemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes["System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy"];
WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linktypeEnd = workitemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds[linkType.ReverseEnd.Name];
 wi.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(linktypeEnd, wiID));
 wi.Save();
```